# When should an operation be said to have started? When it starts starting, or when it finishes?

Tags: java, testing, concurrency

Apologies for the strangely worded title, but I'm running into an interesting concurrency issue in my testing. Here's the relevant code:

```
public class CancelableOperation {

     boolean canceled;
     boolean started;

     public void start() {
         if (!canceled) {
             started = true;
             // Kick off actual operation on another thread
         }
     }

     public void cancel() {
         if (!started) {
              canceled = true;
         } else {
              // Attempt to cancel the other operation
         }
     }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    CancelableOperation op = new CancelableOperation();
    op.start();

    while (!op.started) {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }

    op.cancel();
}
```

The issue is that `cancel()` gets called after `started` is `true`, but before the actual operation has kicked off on the new thread. In practice, it takes about 3 milliseconds for the operation to "actually" start, but that's more than enough time for `cancel()` to be called in my test. I can, of course, put a small `Thread.sleep()` in the test (after we've determined that `op.started` is true) to wait for the operation to begin, but I'd like to instead change my code to deal with this edge case.

Obviously, starting the operation on the secondary thread is the root of the problem, but, since the operation is a long, synchronous process, moving it onto this thread isn't feasible. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

> CyclicBarrier. A CyclicBarrier is a synchronizer that allows a set of
>   threads to wait for each other to reach a common execution point, also
>   called a barrier. CyclicBarriers are used in programs in which we have
>   a fixed number of threads that must wait for each other to reach a
>   common point before continuing execution.

So this code will helps you:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

class CancelableOperation {

    boolean canceled;
    boolean started;
    public static final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    public CancelableOperation() {
        gate.reset();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!canceled) {
            System.out.println("started");
            started = true;
            try {
                gate.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Kick off actual operation on another thread
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            gate.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!started) {
            System.out.println("canceled");
            canceled = true;
        } else {
            // Attempt to cancel the other operation
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CancelableOperation op = new CancelableOperation();
        new Thread(op::start).start();
        new Thread(op::cancel).start();

    }
}
```

So if `cancel()` reach to `gate.await();` it will lock until `start()` reach to kick off another thread